# How to read the content of a PDF using Adobe Acrobat?

Tags: pdf, acrobat, acrobat-sdk

Is there a way to read pdf documents with any api adobe acrobat available without converting to any format such as word/excel?

Answer (score 0):

One can use the [Adobe PDF Extract API](https://www.adobe.io/document-services/apis/pdf-extract/) ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20220129022123/https://www.adobe.io/document-services/apis/pdf-extract/)) to get access to the content of a PDF file:

> Unlock the structure and content elements of any PDF with a web service powered by Adobe Sensei's machine learning.

[image]